# R and parallelization

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am quite a newbie in parallel processing and I'd like some advices.

My R program has a structure as follows :

```
Data reading
Preliminary calculations

vector1 <- array(NA,sim=nsim)
vector2 <- array(NA,sim=nsim)
for (i in 1:nsim)
{
some calculations involving some global variables and 
whose results are saved in vector1 and vector2
}
Final calculations using vector1 and vector2
```

This loop is really time consuming and I was wondering which R package could offer me the best way to parallelize it. Do u have any ideas ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The loop is easy to rewrite for use of the `foreach` package. On Linux I've had good experiences using `foreach` with the `doMC` backend. See [this introduction](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doMC/vignettes/gettingstartedMC.pdf).

Comment: However, I suspect the loop could be rewritten to be much more efficient.

Comment: Can you rewrite the loop in an lapply call ? If yes, you can use parLapply (from package parallel).

Comment: Thanks for your answers. This 'foreach' package looks nice, but I see it works only on Linux or MacOS based systems. And it is clearly impossible to rewrite the loop using an lapply call (this is basically a bootstrapped GLM with some refinements).

Comment: `foreach` works (nearly every day for me) on windows, too. See the `snow` and `doSNOW` packages for setting up a variety of parallel backends. It's `doMC` that only works with linux-like machines with the ability to fork processes.